# Conditional operator in JS - Failed syntax error

Tags: javascript

I wonder what is wrong with the following conditional operator in JS.

```
function somehting(){
   jsonVal = ['test', 'test2'];
   return (jsonVal.length > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

It is complaining on the first paranthesis `(`

Comment: you could just write `return !!jsonVal.length`

Comment: The way you've written it, `jsonVal` is a global (but that shouldn't result in the ternary failing).

Comment: @F.Calderan `Boolean(jsonVal.length)` or `true == jsonVal.length` would be more explicit and thus clearer (but the latter might cause jsonlint to complain about the `==` comparison.)

Comment: @kojiro it's better always use triple equality `===`

Comment: @F.Calderan Are you sure about that? Please take another look at the context.

Comment: Surry guys my wrong. it was JSON.parse() that was causing the syntax problem. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted works fine, you probably have a syntax error elsewhere in the file.

```
return (jsonVal.length > 0) ? true : false;
```

can also be written as:

```
return jsonVal.length > 0;
```